# Get "connection refused" when I try to connect from one container to another over https

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2019

Im using asp .net core and visual Studio 2019

I have two container, one web and one webapi. I try to connect from the "web" to my "webapi". This works fine when I dont check the "configure for https"-checkbox in the webapi-project (via http://my-web-api/api/values/)

But when I check the "configure for https"-checkbox in the webapi-project I get "connection refused", no matter if I try to reach it over http or https.

What to do?

[image]

Comment: this name is not resolvable > http://my-web-api/api/values/ , please explain what your "configure for https" button works/adds to config, question is kinda vague, needs improvement.

Comment: I just made that up. I run locally..

Comment: Maybe this will work  :) https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/master/samples/aspnetapp/aspnetcore-docker-https.md

Comment: @DusanGligoric: I added an image, thanks for your input

Comment: If this is some sort of managed docker orchestrator/deployment tool its more of a question for users of that platform rather than docker globally

Comment: Its Visual Studio 2019